# opengl with Nvidia gpu

Tags: linux, opengl, gpu, nvidia

I have finished a project with opengl functions , which display 3D graph.
Then I plug a Nvidia gpu into my PC. Since the project can be running without Nvidia gpu, how can I control the opengl functions are running on the resource of the Nvidia gpu rather than origial cpu?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no built-in OpenGL functions for this very purpose. However, some extensions would do. [`WGL_NV_gpu_affinity`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/gpu_affinity.txt) shall work for NVIDIA cards.
Also see [Select a graphic device in windows + opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036292/select-a-graphic-device-in-windows-opengl) and [Is there a way to programmatically select the rendering GPU in a multi-GPU environment? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306190/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-select-the-rendering-gpu-in-a-multi-gpu-envir)

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer! The functions that I wang to call is just the basic functions of opengl, such as glVertex ,etc. How can I make sure that those functions are running on Nvidia GPU?

Comment: @mengyang I guess I didn't make it clear.. There's no guarantee that which graphics card is used to render on, you shall use things like `WGL_NV_affinity` to explicitly set it.