# How to make Flutter run on GPU-1

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

When running flutter Windows application it defaults to GPU-0.

In my case GPU-0 is the default motherboard Intel UHD Graphics 630 processor.
I also have a NVIDIA Quadro T1000 as GPU-1.

How I can instruct Flutter to run on GPU-1?

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @cbraken:

I can imagine energy conscious users (e.g. laptop users) may want the opposite behavior. I imagine what you might want is something like new functionality in the API we expose to the C++ bits of the Flutter template that developers could use to specify whether their app would like to request to take advantage of the more performant GPU?

For one-off scenarios, you should be able to set this manually for your own use:
https://www.howtogeek.com/351522/how-to-choose-which-gpu-a-game-uses-on-windows-10/

It doesn't appear that there's any such Windows API for doing this, but you could have the C++ runner portion of your Flutter app do this with a registry setting, though it's not picked up until the next run:
[Programmatically set Graphics Performance for an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732181/programmatically-set-graphics-performance-for-an-app)

I'm not a Direct3D wizard, but a bit of quick searching didn't turn up any obvious API for this that wasn't driver-specific. If people have pointers, it's something we might consider. In the meantime, a few pointers to pages I ran into in a quick search:

[Is there a way to programmatically select the rendering GPU in a multi-GPU environment? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306190/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-select-the-rendering-gpu-in-a-multi-gpu-envir)
[Forcing Machine to Use Dedicated Graphics Card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823372/forcing-machine-to-use-dedicated-graphics-card)